# SOSL using POST REST /parameterizedSearch API

Tags: rest-api, rest, sosl, parameterizedsearch

I got the "/services/data/v46.0/parameterizedSearch" POST API working for a complex SOSL search I want to perform.

I am referring to the Salesforce documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_parameterized.htm

My requirement is, I wish to find an email address by only searching the email fields and have the request json payload tailored to do so

```
POST /services/data/v46.0/parameterizedSearch
{
  "q":"mytestemail+test@example.com",
  "fields":["Id", "external_id__c"],
  "in": "EMAIL",
  "sobjects": [{"name":"Account"}]
}
```

Per my understanding if I use "in": "PHONE" it should not yield any results but it does.

```
POST /services/data/v46.0/parameterizedSearch
{
  "q":"mytestemail+test@example.com",
  "fields":["Id", "external_id__c"],
  "in": "PHONE",
  "sobjects": [{"name":"Account"}]
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: All, I have created a case with Salesforce support and it appears that this function is not working as designed / documented. I have not received an official word yet but making my deduction per number of days it is still with the support pending investigation.

Comment: Salesforce support confirmed that the functionality does not work as documented. Here's the knowledge article: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GSK4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce support confirmed that the functionality does not work as documented. Here's the knowledge article: success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GSK4

Comment: This is fixed as of Spring '20 release.